# Tomcat Web Service inside Docker container returns HTTP 500 caused by NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, web-services, docker, tomcat

I’m trying to call my WebService which is running on a Tomcat 9.0.12 inside a Docker container.

My Tomcat seems to be configured correctly because when I deploy my WebService onto it without Docker I can call it like: https://localhost:8843/foo/services/foo?wsdl

If I call the service via Browser it returns HTTP Status 500 and as Root Cause I get NoSuchMethodError

If I try to call the service when it runs inside a Docker container it will fail (see exception below) the strange thing right now is that when I call https://localhost:8843/foo/services Tomcat will list all my Web Services including the one above.

Even when I look inside my application log files there is no exception etc. the service is just starting as normal.

**Exception:**

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

**Root Caused:**

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:org.codehaus.stax2.ri.EmptyIterator.getInstance()Lorg/codehaus/stax2/ri/EmptyIterator;
at com.ctc.wstx.sw.OutputElementBase.getPrefixes(OutputElementBase.java:358)
at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.writeStartElement(StaxUtils.java:811)
at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.copy(StaxUtils.java:758)
at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.copy(StaxUtils.java:722)
at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.copy(StaxUtils.java:648)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.SchemaSerializer.writeXml(SchemaSerializer.java:58)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.SchemaSerializer.marshall(SchemaSerializer.java:49)
at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLWriterImpl.printExtensibilityElements(WSDLWriterImpl.java:998)
at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLWriterImpl.printTypes(WSDLWriterImpl.java:882)
at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLWriterImpl.printDefinition(WSDLWriterImpl.java:131)
at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLWriterImpl.writeWSDL(WSDLWriterImpl.java:1073)
at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLWriterImpl.getDocument(WSDLWriterImpl.java:1038)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.WSDLGetUtils.writeWSDLDocument(WSDLGetUtils.java:705)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.WSDLGetUtils.getDocument(WSDLGetUtils.java:151)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.WSDLGetInterceptor.getDocument(WSDLGetInterceptor.java:129)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.WSDLGetInterceptor.handleMessage(WSDLGetInterceptor.java:77)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:216)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:301)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:225)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:276)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:607)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

If you need any further information just comment and tell me what you need!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by adding following dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.woodstox/stax2-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
    <artifactId>stax2-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```